# how to pivot a sql table from rows to columns with python/pandas/numpy

Tags: python, sql, pandas, bitwise-operators

I have a dictionary table with bit mask ids
see below:

[image: Origin data]

I'd like to transform it to this structure:
each row's tag will become a column and it's value will be the combination (bitwise).

**example**:
the value 3 is a combination of **1 and 2** therefore a will be given 1 and b will given 1 and all the rest of the columns are 0

[image: destination table]

I've implemented it using a SQL Server stored procedure with bitwise operator "&".
I'd like to implement this transform using python (I assume it would be done with pandas),
As you can each tag is 2 to the power of n, so I tried to tackle it using a transformation from decimal to binary - which give me exactly what I need, but I'm missing the stage of how to attach each bit to the correct column
example 3 is represented as 11 in binary so I'd like to assign a with 1 and b with 1 and all the rest should be 0.

the source table may be added additional entries so the output should alter the destination table with the new row (for example n , 4096) as a new column m which will be assign 1 or 0 depending the value.

Any suggestions how to approach this using python/pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use numpy broadcasting with bit shifting (`>>`) for convert integers to columns filled by binaries, last for new column with all combinations is used [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) with columns names and separators:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'mask_id':range(1, 17)})

#list or Series of tags
L = list('abcdefghijklm')
#L = df2['Tags']

a = df.mask_id.to_numpy()
n = len(L)
data = (a[:, None] >> np.arange(n)) & 1

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=df.index, columns=L)

df1['combinations'] = df1.dot(df1.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',')
print (df1)
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m combinations
0   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0            a
1   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0            b
2   1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0          a,b
3   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0            c
4   1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0          a,c
5   0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0          b,c
6   1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        a,b,c
7   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0            d
8   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0          a,d
9   0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0          b,d
10  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        a,b,d
11  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0          c,d
12  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        a,c,d
13  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        b,c,d
14  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0      a,b,c,d
15  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0            e
```

If need combinations in lists use list comprehension:

```
cols = df1.columns.to_numpy()
df1['combinations'] = [cols[x].tolist() for x in df1.to_numpy().astype(bool)]
print (df1)
    a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  combinations
0   1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0           [a]
1   0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0           [b]
2   1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        [a, b]
3   0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0           [c]
4   1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        [a, c]
5   0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        [b, c]
6   1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     [a, b, c]
7   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0           [d]
8   1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        [a, d]
9   0  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        [b, d]
10  1  1  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     [a, b, d]
11  0  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0        [c, d]
12  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     [a, c, d]
13  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0     [b, c, d]
14  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  [a, b, c, d]
15  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0           [e]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want binary representations, here is one without previous dataset needed:

```
cols = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l']
df = [list(('0'*(12-1)+"{0:b}".format(1))[::-1])]
for i in range(16):
    n = "{0:b}".format(i)
    df = df + [list(('0'*(12-len(n))+n)[::-1])]
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = cols)
df["combinations"] = df.apply(lambda x: list(x[x == '1'].index) ,axis = 1)
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   combinations
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [a]
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   []
2   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [a]
3   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [b]
4   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [a, b]
5   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [c]
6   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [a, c]
7   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [b, c]
8   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [a, b, c]
9   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [d]
10  1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [a, d]
11  0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [b, d]
12  1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [a, b, d]
13  0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [c, d]
14  1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [a, c, d]
15  0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [b, c, d]
16  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   [a, b, c, d]
```